# SwiftUI - Optional Timer, reset and recreate

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, nstimer, combine

Normally, I would use an optional variable to hold my `Timer` reference, as it's nice to be able to **invalidate** and set it to `nil` before recreating.

I'm trying to use `SwiftUI` and want to make sure I'm correctly doing so...

I declare as:

```
@State var timer:Publishers.Autoconnect<Timer.TimerPublisher>? = nil
```

Later I:

```
self.timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```

To drive a UI text control I use:

```
.onReceive(timer) { time in
    print("The time is now \(time)")
}
```

What is the right way with this `Combine` typed `Timer` to invalidate and recreate?

I've read one should call:

`self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()`

However, do I also need to **invalidate** or simply then `nil` out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no need to throw away the `TimerPublisher` itself. `Timer.publish` creates a `Timer.TimerPublisher` instance, which like all other publishers, only starts emitting values when you create a subscription to it - and it stops emitting as soon as the subscription is closed.

So instead of recreating the `TimerPublisher`, you just need to recreate the subscription to it - when the need arises.

So assign the `Timer.publish` on declaration, but don't `autoconnect()` it. Whenever you want to start the timer, call `connect` on it and save the `Cancellable` in an instance property. Then whenever you want to stop the timer, call `cancel` on the `Cancellable` and set it to `nil`.

You can find below a fully working view with a preview that starts the timer after 5 seconds, updates the view every second and stops streaming after 30 seconds.

This can be improved further by storing the publisher and the subscription on a view model and just injecting that into the view.

```
struct TimerView: View {
    @State private var text: String = "Not started"

    private var timerSubscription: Cancellable?

    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .onReceive(timer) {
                self.text = "The time is now \($0)"
            }
    }

    mutating func startTimer() {
        timerSubscription = timer.connect()
    }

    mutating func stopTimer() {
        timerSubscription?.cancel()
        timerSubscription = nil
    }
}

struct TimerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        var timerView = TimerView()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            timerView.startTimer()
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30) {
            timerView.stopTimer()
        }
        return timerView
    }
}
```

With a view model, you don't even need to expose a `TimerPublisher` (or any `Publisher`) to the view, but can simply update an `@Published` property and display that in the `body` of your view. This enables you to declare `timer` as `autoconnect`, which means you don't manually need to call `cancel` on it, you can simply `nil` out the subscription reference to stop the timer.

```
class TimerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    private var timerSubscription: Cancellable?

    @Published var time: Date = Date()

    func startTimer() {
        timerSubscription = timer.assign(to: \.time, on: self)
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        timerSubscription = nil
    }
}

struct TimerView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TimerViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.time.description)
    }
}

struct TimerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let viewModel = TimerViewModel()
        let timerView = TimerView(viewModel: viewModel)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            viewModel.startTimer()
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30) {
            viewModel.stopTimer()
        }
        return timerView
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! quick extra question, I thought the $var (binding) access was only used for manipulation of @State variables, and otherwise we just use var (without the $ prefix)?

Comment: There are no `$` usages in my code, since there are no bindings passed around. From the documentation of `Binding`: _"Applying the $ prefix to a property wrapped value returns its projectedValue, which for a state property wrapper returns a binding to the value."_. So yes, you only need to use the `$` prefix when you want to pass around `Binding`s between different types.

Comment: This is nice but is a one-off. After cancelling the time, even if you start it again, onReceive for time will not be triggered again.

Also, in the first example, because timerSubscription and timer are not defined as states, they will be reinitialized with default values on every other state change of the view.